# How to create a program that is able to search for a character and replace it with another word?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, logging

I have huge logs to look through and need to replace some parts of the logs to a more generic profile.

For example, in the logs, there are many email address. Email address are recorded as such. There are no criteria to how the emails are records:

abc@gmail.com

abc_efg@gmail.com

Anyone have any knowledge on how to convert this email address using ReGex, to convert abc to user, regardless on how the email was stored as seen below?:
@gmail.com

The purpose of this program is so that I am able to hide the email address of the users, before sending the file to someone else.

Tried to use RegEx but I am not sure on how to proceed.

Hope someone is able to help! Thanks

Comment: Please include what attempts you have already made.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`import re`

`text = 'this is my email Kapil@gmail.com or may be not'`

`re.sub('[A-Za-z0-9_]*@.*\.com', '********', text)`

This will take all the words contains alphanumeric sequence or _ then check it they contains '@' next and followed by your domain name which can be gmail or any other comapany name ending with .com

All these condition will ensure the sequence of word we captured is an email and it will replace than email with '********'.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with an explanation for why you believe it accurately answers the OP's question.